# How to SSO Java web application with Active Directory

Tags: tomcat, active-directory, spring-security, single-sign-on

I have a corporate network that users login via **Active Directory** and going to deploy a Java web Application which uses **Spring Security** and runs on **Tomcat**. So, I would like to create this **single sign-on** mechanism that enables users to login intranet websites without entering credentials after logging into their accounts on Active Directory.

Briefly people are logging in via active directory and don't want to login again to intranet web applications, so i have to get their sessions and complete authentication and authorization steps accordingly.

I think i should implement Java and Spring Security NTLM authentication.

I might consider the usage of OpenAM or JASIG Cas or etc.

What kind of structure i would use, any suggestions?

Comment: Burry that NLTM crap right now. It is deprecated, unsecure and proprietary.

Comment: I wish to :) but unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent users from writing logins and passwords, and logged automatically I would recommend you use the Spring [Security Kerberos/SPNEGO Extension](https://spring.io/blog/2009/09/28/spring-security-kerberos-spnego-extension).
If you use JASIG Cas, users will be redirected to the CAS login page and enter their credentials.